# Differentiate between Observables, Subjects, ReplaySubjects, Behaviour Subjects?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, web-frontend

Please share some examples/code snippets. I read the code but my understanding is not that clear.

Comment: https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-subjects-5c585188c3e1

Comment: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This isn't a horrible question at its core, but to avoid the downvotes, you should probably rephrase so that you have example code, maybe two or three snippets, where you're not sure which to use to explain why you're asking it. Make sense?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can picture them all as streams.

- **Observable**: Subscribe to it to get the values
- **Subject**: Same but you also have control of the values that you want to `emit` into it (can subscribe to it but also emit)
- **ReplaySubject**: Same as subject but will keep track of the N latest emitted values and every time you subscribe to it, it'll emit those N values
- **BehaviorSubject**: Subject where you have to set a default value, if you subscribe to it before anything has been emitted you'll get the default value

**Observable and Subject**: If you emit a value and subscribe to one of them after that, you'll not get the latest value emitted, you'll have to wait for a new value to be emitted before you're notified

**ReplaySubject and BehaviorSubject**: Even if you emit a value and then subscribe to one of them, you'll directly get the latest emitted value as soon as you subscribe.